# ASM330LHH didn't work in I2C with STM32 BLUENRG-LP

Tags: stm32, i2c, imu

Here I used STM32 BLUENRG-LP SoC with ​ASM330LHH. We have the same schematic design in steval-IBD11V2A, like the first image. The second one is our schematic design.

[image]
[image]

My I2C configuration init function is like:

```
/**
  * @brief  Configures the I2C interface used for the sensor ASM330LHH.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void BSP_I2C_Init(void)
{
  /* Initialize the GPIOs associated to the I2C port */
  BSP_I2C_DATA_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();
  LL_GPIO_SetPinMode(BSP_I2C_DATA_GPIO_PORT, BSP_I2C_DATA_PIN, LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE);
  LL_GPIO_SetPinSpeed(BSP_I2C_DATA_GPIO_PORT, BSP_I2C_DATA_PIN, 
  LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH);
  LL_GPIO_SetPinOutputType(BSP_I2C_DATA_GPIO_PORT, BSP_I2C_DATA_PIN, 
  LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_OPENDRAIN);
  LL_GPIO_SetPinPull(BSP_I2C_DATA_GPIO_PORT, BSP_I2C_DATA_PIN, BSP_I2C_DATA_GPIO_PULL);
  BSP_I2C_DATA_GPIO_AF();
  
  BSP_I2C_CLK_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();
  LL_GPIO_SetPinMode(BSP_I2C_CLK_GPIO_PORT, BSP_I2C_CLK_PIN, LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE);
  LL_GPIO_SetPinSpeed(BSP_I2C_CLK_GPIO_PORT, BSP_I2C_CLK_PIN, LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH);
  LL_GPIO_SetPinOutputType(BSP_I2C_CLK_GPIO_PORT, BSP_I2C_CLK_PIN, 
  LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_OPENDRAIN);
  LL_GPIO_SetPinPull(BSP_I2C_CLK_GPIO_PORT, BSP_I2C_CLK_PIN, BSP_I2C_CLK_GPIO_PULL);
  BSP_I2C_CLK_GPIO_AF();
  
  /* Initialize the I2C clock */
  BSP_I2C_CLK_ENABLE();
  
  LL_I2C_Disable(BSP_I2C);
   
  /* Configure the SDA setup, hold time and the SCL high, low period
   * For Fast-mode 400 kHz, PRESC | 0h | SCLDEL | SDADEL | SCLH | SCLL
   *                          1h  | 0h |    3h  |   2h   |  03h |  09h
   */
  __IO uint32_t timing = __LL_I2C_CONVERT_TIMINGS(0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0xF, 0x13);
  printf("timing in BSP_I2C_Init: %#x, \r\n", timing);
  LL_I2C_SetTiming(BSP_I2C, timing);
  //  LL_I2C_SetTiming(BSP_I2C, 0x10320309);
  //  LL_I2C_SetTiming(BSP_I2C, 0x00200204);
    
   
  /* Enable Clock stretching */
  LL_I2C_EnableClockStretching(BSP_I2C);
   
  /* Enable Peripheral in I2C mode */
  LL_I2C_SetMode(BSP_I2C, LL_I2C_MODE_I2C);
   
  /* Enable the I2C peripheral */
  LL_I2C_Enable(BSP_I2C);
   
  /* Enable I2C transfer complete/error interrupts:
   *  - Enable Receive Interrupt
   *  - Enable Not acknowledge received interrupt
   *  - Enable Error interrupts
   *  - Enable Stop interrupt
   */
  //  LL_I2C_EnableIT_TX(BSP_I2C);
  //  LL_I2C_EnableIT_RX(BSP_I2C);
  //  LL_I2C_EnableIT_TC(BSP_I2C);
  //  LL_I2C_EnableIT_NACK(BSP_I2C);
  //  LL_I2C_EnableIT_ERR(BSP_I2C);
  //  LL_I2C_EnableIT_STOP(BSP_I2C);
}
```

When I tried to use API, I can't get whoamI ID. The result is 0.

```
#ifdef TEST_INERTIAL_SENSOR



   /* Initialize the handle of the LPS22HH driver */

   inertialHandle.write_reg = BSP_I2C_Write;

   inertialHandle.read_reg = BSP_I2C_Read;
 
    
 
   /* Inizialize the I2C */
 
   BSP_I2C_Init();
     
   LL_mDelay(1000);
 
    
     
   /* Wait sensor boot time */
     
   LL_mDelay(BOOT_TIME);
     
   /* Check device ID */
     
   uint8_t result;
     
   asm330lhh_status_reg_t reg;
     
   result = asm330lhh_device_id_get(&inertialHandle, &whoamI);
     
   result = asm330lhh_status_reg_get(&inertialHandle,&reg);
 
   printf("whoamI: %d, \r\n", whoamI);
 
   printf("ID: %d, \r\n", ASM330LHH_ID);
 
   printf("result: %d, \r\n", result);
```

The **BSP_I2C_Write** and **BSP_I2C_Read** is like this:

```
/**
  * @brief  I2C write function used for the ASM330LHH IMU sensor.
  * @param  handle: handle. 
  * @param  Reg: Reg. 
  * @param  pBuff: pBuff. 
  * @param  nBuffSize: nBuffSize. 
  * @retval None
  */
int32_t BSP_I2C_Write(void *handle, uint8_t Reg, uint8_t *pBuff, uint16_t nBuffSize)
{
  /* Initialize the handle transfer */
  LL_I2C_HandleTransfer(BSP_I2C, ASM330LHH_I2C_ADD_L, LL_I2C_ADDRSLAVE_7BIT, nBuffSize+1, LL_I2C_MODE_AUTOEND, LL_I2C_GENERATE_START_WRITE);

  /* Wait for the TX Empty flag */
  while(LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TXE(BSP_I2C) == 0); /* TODO: add a SW timeout */

  /* Get the received byte from the RX FIFO */
  LL_I2C_TransmitData8(BSP_I2C, (Reg | 0x80)); // |0x80 auto-increment

  /* Wait for the TX Empty flag */
  while(LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TXE(BSP_I2C) == 0); /* TODO: add a SW timeout */

  for(uint16_t i = 0; i < nBuffSize; i++) {
    /* Wait for the TX flag */
    while(LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TXIS(BSP_I2C) == 0); /* TODO: add a SW timeout */

    /* Fill the TX FIFO with data */
    LL_I2C_TransmitData8(BSP_I2C, pBuff[i]);
  }

  /* Wait for the Transfer Complete flag */
  //  while(LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TC(BSP_I2C) == 0);

  return 0;
}

/**
  * @brief  I2C read function used for the ASM330LHH IMU sensor.
  * @param  handle: handle. 
  * @param  Reg: Reg. 
  * @param  pBuff: pBuff. 
  * @param  nBuffSize: nBuffSize. 
  * @retval None
  */
int32_t BSP_I2C_Read(void *handle, uint8_t Reg, uint8_t *pBuff, uint16_t nBuffSize)
{
  /* Initialize the handle transfer */
  LL_I2C_HandleTransfer(BSP_I2C, ASM330LHH_I2C_ADD_L, LL_I2C_ADDRSLAVE_7BIT, 1,             
  LL_I2C_MODE_AUTOEND, LL_I2C_GENERATE_START_WRITE);
  
  /* Wait for the TX Empty flag */
  while(LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TXE(BSP_I2C) == 0); /* TODO: add a SW timeout */
  
  /* Get the received byte from the RX FIFO */
  LL_I2C_TransmitData8(BSP_I2C, (Reg | 0x80)); // |0x80 auto-increment
  
  /* Wait for the TX Empty flag */
  while(LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TXE(BSP_I2C) == 0); /* TODO: add a SW timeout */
      
  /* Wait for the Transfer Complete flag */
  //  while(LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TC(BSP_I2C) == 0);  
      
  /* Initialize the handle transfer */
  LL_I2C_HandleTransfer(BSP_I2C, ASM330LHH_I2C_ADD_L, LL_I2C_ADDRSLAVE_7BIT, nBuffSize,     
  LL_I2C_MODE_AUTOEND, LL_I2C_GENERATE_START_READ);

  for(uint16_t i = 0; i < nBuffSize; i++) {
    /* Wait for the RX Not Empty flag */
    while(LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(BSP_I2C) == 0); /* TODO: add a SW timeout */

    /* Get the received byte from the RX FIFO */
    pBuff[i] = LL_I2C_ReceiveData8(BSP_I2C);
  }

  /* Wait for the Transfer Complete flag */
  //    while(LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TC(BSP_I2C) == 0);
  
  return 0;
}
```

I don't know where the problem is. Please do me a favor for the insight.

----------------------- Solved ---------------------------------

Comment: There’s many possibilities for error - you need to narrow down these. Have you considered the fault might not be with the schematic or the code you’ve shown? Is it hardware, software or both? My first step would be to use a logic analyser or oscilloscope on the i2c signals to see what it happening.

Comment: Where is the I2C address of the sensor set? Why R8? The datasheet says ‘tied’ to cdd. No mention of a resistor.

Comment: I've got the oscilloscope to test it. From the screenshot, I get "110101000" by LL_I2C_Handletransfer. And "100011110" by LL_I2C_TransmitData8. It seems the I2C communication is correct.

Comment: Hi @Kartman, thanks for your information. Finally, I figured out where the problem is. I changed codes `LL_I2C_TransmitData8(BSP_I2C, (Reg | 0x80)); ` to `LL_I2C_TransmitData8(BSP_I2C, Reg ); ` in both  `BSP_I2C_Write` and  `BSP_I2C_Read`. Then it works. I don't know why to use  `Reg|0x80` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out where the problem is. I changed the codes: (in both `BSP_I2C_Write` and `BSP_I2C_Read`.)

From:

```
LL_I2C_TransmitData8(BSP_I2C, (Reg | 0x80));
```

To:

```
LL_I2C_TransmitData8(BSP_I2C, Reg);
```

Here raised a new question: Why we sometimes need `Reg | 0x80`, sometimes not?

Comment: Thanks for coming back and writing a self-answer, it might be useful for future users who come across your question!

Comment: I’m glad you persisted and found your problem. Knowing how to debug is a valuable skill. As for when to Reg | 0x80 or not is dependent on the context. Assuming ‘Reg’ is the value you wish to write, whether you want bit 7 set or not in that value purely depends on the register you’re writing to and what bit 7 represents in terms of function. Since your code was derived from one intended for a different device, then you’d need to refer to that datasheet to determine the significance.